# Change Runlevel In RHEL 7/CENTOS 7 with SystemD

Tags: rhel, systemd

I want to switch runlevel in CentOS 7 so that I can patch application. I tried to switch runlevel from 3 to 2 by executing below command but after reboot it still shows runlevel 3.

Want to know if there any method/command to do it.

```
ln -s /lib/systemd/system/runlevel2.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you wish to do is temporarily change to runlevel 2, invoke:

`# sysemctl isolate multi-user.target`

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://access.redhat.com/articles/754933), I could see the following.

```
Traditional runlevel      New target name     Symbolically linked to...
Runlevel 0           |    runlevel0.target -> poweroff.target
Runlevel 1           |    runlevel1.target -> rescue.target
Runlevel 2           |    runlevel2.target -> multi-user.target
Runlevel 3           |    runlevel3.target -> multi-user.target
Runlevel 4           |    runlevel4.target -> multi-user.target
Runlevel 5           |    runlevel5.target -> graphical.target
Runlevel 6           |    runlevel6.target -> reboot.target
```

To get the current set `runlevel` :

```
# systemctl get-default
```

So to change the `runlevel`in RHEL 7, try using `systemctl` command to change the runlevel. Since `runlevel 2` is emulated by `multi-user.target`

```
# systemctl isolate multi-user.target
# systemctl isolate runlevel2.target
# systemctl set-default multi-user.target

# rm '/etc/systemd/system/default.target'
# ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target' '/etc/systemd/system/default.target'
```

The same can be found in this red hat [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Targets.html).

Comment: Why are you invoking two different targets,  using `rm` to remove a target and  then `ln` to set a new default target?   This is just wrong!

Comment: lets say, default target of the system was pointing to another `runlevel`, other than `2`, so remove and create a fresh one. Whats wrong with it ?

Comment: I followed above steps and rebooted machine, but still I can see runlevel 3. I am getting below output.

#runlevel
N 3

How to confirm the system is booted up in runlevel 2.